# if a check is in your son's name in c/o you does it have to be signed by your son

Tags: banking, check

Second name on check c/o son's check need advice

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in?  Is your son an adult -- in the sense that he is old enough to sign binding contracts without your consent -- or an "emancipated minor"?  Are you legally his parent or "legal guardian"?

Comment: Have you asked your bank?  No matter what answer we give, your bank gets to set its own policies so as to balance customer convenience with the bank's legal obligations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will need to be signed by him unless he is a minor, you have power-of-attorney or you have some sort of other legal guardianship (such as if he is medically incapacitated and you are his executor). A c/o line does not mean the check was made out jointly to you, only that it could be delivered to you and you are entrusted to pass it on to him (your son).